# Get permutations with a particular first element

Tags: haskell, permutation

how can I get conditioned permutations in Haskell?

This is my code:

```
perm :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
perm [] = [[]]
perm xs = [ x:ps | x <- xs , ps <- perm ( xs\\[x] ) ]
```

But I want to get all the permutations that begins with 1. When I execute:

```
perm [1,2,3]
```

I want to get just this:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2]]
```

I want to put some condition in the function "perm" that allows me to do this while its doing the permutations, I don't want to do a filter because I don't want to calculate all the permutations.

Answer (score 3):

The permutations of `[1, 2, 3]` that start with `1` are just the permutations of `[2, 3]` with `1` added to the front, which you can calculate using

```
map (1:) . perm $ [2, 3]
```